# Breusch-Godfrey Test for autocorrelation

Tags: r, time-series, hypothesis-testing, self-study, autocorrelation

Following the steps of [Breusch–Godfrey test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breusch%E2%80%93Godfrey_test#Procedure) , I wrote my own `R` code which differs from the `R` function for `bgtest` under package 'lmtest' . Though both of them reject the null hypothesis that at least one $\rho$ is statistically significant .

I have $30$ observations in my data set and I set the null hypothesis that :
$$\rho_1=\rho_2=\rho_3=\rho_4=\rho_5=0$$

```
 data <- read.csv("exc12.26.csv",header=TRUE)

 lC <- log(C); lI <- log(I); lL <- log(L); lH <- log(H); lA <- log(A)

 lm.y <- lm(lC~lI+lL+lH+lA)
 uhat <- resid(lm.y)

 ##BG test :
 ut_1 <-uhat[5:29];ut_2 <-uhat[4:28];ut_3 <-uhat[3:27];ut_4 <-uhat[2:26];ut_5 <-uhat[1:25]

lm.u <- lm(uhat[6:30]~lI[6:30]+lL[6:30]+lH[6:30]+lA[6:30]+ut_1+ut_2+ut_3+ut_4+ut_5)

summary(lm.u)
R2 <- 0.4943 
chi_cal <- 25*R2

p_val <- pchisq(chi_cal,5,lower.tail=FALSE)
p_val
[1] 0.03020434
```

But if I use the function `bgtest` , the p-value does not match with my R-code p-value .

```
 library(lmtest)
 bgtest(lm.y,order=5,type="Chisq")

 ##Output : p-value = 0.01396

 detach(data)
```

Where am i doing mistake ?

Comment: Do the test statistics match while the p-values do not match? Or do the test statistics not match either? You can always check the code behind an R function by typing the function name and clicking "Enter". That way you could see whether the `bgtest` code does something different from what your code does.

Comment: @RichardHardy No , statistics also do not match .

Comment: That means you have defined the statistic differently than in `bgtest`. You could either look for mistakes in your code or -- if you do not trust `bgtest` -- take a look at the source code of `bgtest`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your implementation of the test statistic omits the lagged residuals for the first five observations, i.e., sets the starting values to `NA`. However, the implementation in the `bgtest()` function by default sets the starting values to `0`. You can change the default, though, by setting `fill = NA`.

I hope this resolves the discrepancy. I couldn't check for your data without a reproducible example.

Comment: I wrote `bgtest(lm.y,order=5,type="Chisq",fill=NA)` but it shows error massage `unused argument in bgtest()`

Comment: The feature was added in lmtest 0.9-31 (and the current version is 0.9-34). Probably you have installed an older version.